# How can I split a string from every word in an array with the split method and then compare it to an array?

Tags: python

I Was wondering how to make a string turn into an array of every word and I came across the `.split()` function and that split it, but now I want to compare it to another array. How can I do that?

```
keywords = ["help", "where", "find"]


x = input("How can I help: ")
search = x.split(" ")

for search in keywords:
    if search == keywords:
        print("it looks like you need help with: ", keywords)
    else:
        print("I did not understand")
        print(search, " ", keywords)
```

I dont really know what to do and any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why are you splitting the user input and then (effectively) ignoring the result?

Comment: What do you mean for 'compare' to another list. There are plenty of ways to compare 2 lists... Their lenght, their distance, their similarity as a phrase... Can you specify please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `for (iterating variable) in list`, you can't use an already defined variable name for the iterating variable ! this variable takes the value of every word you're iterating through in your list, one after the other.

Hope this helps ! I tried keeping as much of your own code as simple as possible. If you're looking for a more optimized solution, use [user2390182's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76412301/16880681).

Feel free to ask further questions if needed.

```py
keywords = ["help", "where", "find"]

x = input("How can I help: ")
search = x.split(" ")

success = False
for word in search : #iterate through each word of variable 'search'
    if word in keywords: #if the word we're currently iterating is in the list 'keywords' :
        print("it looks like you need help with: ", word) #we show the word that triggered the 'if'
        success = True #we take note of the fact we successfully helped the user

if not success: 
    print("I did not understand")
    print(search, " ", keywords)

#the 'if' is located after the loop, outside of its scope.
#this way it only triggers once after the loop instead of triggering with each iteration of the loop
```

output :

```
How can I help: i want to find excalibur
it looks like you need help with:  find
```

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely looking for sth like this:

```
search = x.split(" ")  

for kw in keywords:  # don't shadow `search`
    if kw in search:  # do membership  instead of equality test
        print("it looks like you need help with: ", kw)
    else:
        print("I did not understand")
        print(search, " ", keywords)
```